# Regex to exclude URL's

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a JavaScript program to replace certain patterns of text with links. However due to some of the patterns existing within a URL on the page it blocks the URL links.

I am specifically looking to exclude the pattern if it is contained within a URL so for example here is my current Regex code.

```
$els.replaceText(/(\bX00[A-Z0-9]{7}\b)/gi, '<span class="context context_ident">$1<\/span>');
```

Some Example Text:

> item :*X00132BhJk*
>
> www.domain.com/X00132BhJk
>
> www.domainsearch.com/search?ident=X00132BhJk
>
> *X00132BhJk*
>
> *X00132BhJk*

The Italic References should be selected and replaced however the references contained within the domain should not. The issue I have been having is when the reference.

Initially I tried `\sX00[A-Z0-9]{7}\s` but when the reference appears on the far left of the page (First word in the sentence) it doesn't get selected. Equally so it does not select if a full stop follows or a colon precedes.

Is there a way to specifically exclude URL's by excluding / ? and = from being the immediate preceding character but select in all other cases?

Comment: The problem is that `X00132BhJk1 is a perfectly valid URL within an Intranet, for example (specifying a host by that name within the firewall). It's extremely hard to write a regexp for validating URLs. The best you can do is find some invalid cases, such as URLs which include invalid characters, or are malformed in obvious ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture (`^` [start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `|` OR `[^/?=]` in a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) the ones, that must not appear before)

```
/(^|[^\/?=])(\bX00[A-Z0-9]{7}\b)/gi
```

And replace with: `'$1<span class="context context_ident">$2</span>'`

Also [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpdkyy5v/3/); [SO Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075);

Comment: Perfect this has fixed the issue one slight edit /(^|[^/?=]) changed to /(^|[^\/?=]) as the / was escaping the regex declaration too early. I have tested this and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Bobstefano Great, works for you :) Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!^www.*?X00[A-Z0-9]{7}.*$)^(.*?)(X00[A-Z0-9]{7})(.*)$
```

Try this.

Replace with.

```
\1<span class="context context_ident">$1<\/span>\2
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oC3nN4/7

added an m flag as well for multiline match as i have used anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with non-capturing parentheses `(?:)`, in your case `(?:[^/?=]|^)`

```
replace(/(?:[^/?=]|^)(\bX00[A-Z0-9]{7}\b)/gi, '<span class="context context_ident">$1<\/span>');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jqcwmu0j/)

Comment: This looks like it will eat the `/`, `?` or `=` from the URL; because it's non-capture doesn't mean it's not part of the match being replaced

Comment: I first thought the same, but the fiddle shows the opposite.

Comment: Sorry, I got the negate the wrong way in my head; it's a match which is not one of those characters; notice how the `:` disappears; http://jsfiddle.net/jqcwmu0j/1/

Comment: True, better use Jonny 5's answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to  escape the frontslash in the closing `span` tag on the replacement part.

Regex:

```
^((?:(?![\/?]).)*)(X00[A-Z0-9a-z]{7})(.*)$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1<span class="context context_ident">$2</span>$3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iR3nD8/1)